# Are the spikes or prongs in the frill of Ceratopsids considered horns?

Tags: zoology, anatomy, dinosaurs

Many Ceratopsids, mostly of the subfamily Centrosaurinae, have long spikes or prongs sticking out from the edge of the frill, most famously *Styracosaurus*, but also *Diabloceratops* and *Rubeosaurus* and more. Those spikey projections were almost surely sheathed in keratin, which forms the horns in extant species, such as bovids. Are these frill spikes can be considered horns?